# Magento code for $this->getChildHtml('topContainer');

Tags: templates, magento

I am coding a magento theme. I have enabled path hints but in
the header the call to `$this->getChildHtml('topContainer');`
does not reveal any path hints. How can I find out which
.phtml file is loaded when the above call is made, so
that I can create the appropriately named and located
.phtml custom file?

Answer (score 11):

topContainer is a "page/html_wrapper" block.
It means there is no template file associated with it.

The role of this block is to render all it's children blocks inside an html element.
Take a look at the _toHtml() method in 'app/code/core/Mage/Page/Html/Wrapper.php'.

Sincerely,

Jonathan

--- More explanations:

You can take a look at a perfect exemple in:

1. layout/customer.xml (in base theme)
2. layout/sales.xml (in base theme)

You have a similar block:

```
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
```

It's the area where all other blocks of customer account will be rendered.
In order to put the blocks in this area, you have to create a "reference" node with attribute "name" set to the name of the "wrapper".

For exemple if you look (inside sales.xml) to the "sales_order_view" handle, you'll see `<reference name="my.account.wrapper">` and inside this node, other blocks.

These other blocks are classics blocks (core/template) and they have templates files.

So you can compare a 'page/html_wrapper' block to a 'core/text_list' block.
The only difference is the first one will wrap the rendered child block into an html element.

Take a look to the 2 files mentionned above, they will help you a lot.

Comment: Hello, I still don't follow how these blocks with no template files associated with them work. Could someone please explain a bit more?

Comment: I have updated my awnser with more details, hope they will help you

Comment: It is important to note that you should reference `top.container` and not `topContainer` - the former is the name of the block, while the latter is just an alias.